# How to throw and handle custom errors from server to client side in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm building a Next.js application and I'm trying to send custom error messages from the server to the client side when using Next JS new server-side actions. My server-side code is working fine, but I'm having trouble handling custom error types. When I try to catch these errors on the client side, I receive the following error: "Warning: Only plain objects can be passed to Client Components from Server Components. Error objects are not supported."

Here's my client-side code:

```
"use client"
async function handleDelete() {
    try {
        await deleteAddress(contactId, addressId)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e instanceof FetchError) // Is always false
    }
}
```

And here's my server-side code:

```
"use server"
async function deleteAddress(contactId: number, addressId: number) {
    const response = await fetch(process.env.BASE_API_URL + "/contacts/" + contactId + "/addresses/" + addressId, {
        cache: "no-cache",
        method: "DELETE"
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new FetchError("There was a problem with your request", "Something went wrong", "destructive");
    }
}
```

My goal is to catch the FetchError on the client side and handle it appropriately. What is the best way to send custom errors back to the client side in Next.js while avoiding the "Error objects are not supported" issue?

Answer (score 1):

You should serialize the error message into a plain object and then send it to the client.

On the server side (in your server component), create a custom error object and serialize it into a plain object with a message that you can send to the client.

```js
// serverComponent.ts
export async function serverFunction() {
  try {
    // Your server-side code here
    // If an error occurs, create a custom error object
    throw new Error("Custom error message");
  } catch (error) {
    // Serialize the error into a plain object
    return { error: { message: error.message } };
  }
}
```

On the client side (in your client component), check for the error object and handle it accordingly.

```js
// clientComponent.tsx
import { serverFunction } from './serverComponent';

export default function ClientComponent({ error }) {
  if (error) {
    // Handle the error here, such as displaying it to the user
    return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
  }

  // Render the component content when there are no errors
  return <div>Your component content here</div>;
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  // Call the server component function and pass any error object
  const result = await serverFunction();
  
  return {
    props: {
      error: result.error, // Pass the error object to the client component
    },
  };
}
```